# "A noun clause" after em dash?

Tags: em-dash

> Our irresistible tendency to see things in human terms ―
> **that we are often mistaken in attributing complex human
> motives and processing abilities to other species** ― does not
> mean that an animal’s behavior is not, in fact, complex.

The part in bold is a noun cluase? And can I break it down as below?

that/we are often mistaken/in attributing complex human motives and processing abilities/to other species

Comment: It's not a noun clause but a declarative content clause functioning as a supplementary adjunct.

Comment: Wonder what "that" functions for.

Comment: I'd say it's just a subordinator introducing the content clause.

Comment: Subordinator doesn't have a name? I mean clauses have names such as noun, adverb, and adjective clause. I think this "that clause" has construct of "S+V+C" perfectly and if it's not modifying anything, then it's just a sort of a fact that we are~: Noun clause as an appositional clause?

Comment: Subordinator" is its part of speech, and its function is 'marker'. It's not a complement so it can't be S-V-C. And it's not an appositive since they are NPs, not clauses. Its function is that of supplementary adjunct adding non-integrated content. Finite subordinate clauses are classified by the internal structure, either 'relative', 'comparative' or 'content', not by some spurious analogies with the parts of speech. Your that clause belongs to the last category -- content clause.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Many modern grammars of English don't describe clauses as "noun clause" or "adjective clause", based on an analogy with parts of speech.  A word might be a noun or an adjective, not a clause.

This clause could be called a "[content clause](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Content_clause)".  Content clauses can function as subjects, or complements.  In this case, however, the clause is just an additional and optional element Notice how it is set off from the main sentence by dashes.

The word "that" is a subordinator, and it marks the clause as being dependent on some other part of the sentence.  Here, it is an additional description of the "irresistible tendency".

An older grammar would probably agree with most of this. It might call the clause a "noun clause" and say "that" is a "subordinating conjunction"

Comment: Mostly adapted from BillJ's comments.