# "that" is an conjunction but in this sentence what "that" connects with?

Tags: conjunctions

Our irresistible tendency to see things in human terms ―
**that** we are often mistaken in attributing complex human
motives and processing abilities to other species ― does not
mean that an animal’s behavior is not, in fact, complex.

Comment: This is the same question that you asked here.[link](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/272253/a-noun-clause-after-em-dash#comment507855_272253). You should now delete this one.

Answer (score -1):

Here, *that* turns a clause into a noun phrase. A simpler example:

- I like apples.
- That I like apples annoys you.

You **can't** say:

- I like apples annoys you.

So nominalizing *that* gives us a way to turn a clause into a noun phrase.

The rough **semantic** structure of this sentence is:

- *x* – *y* – does not mean that *z*.

This structure can be made clearer by analyzing it as:

- *x* does not mean that *z*.
- *y* does not mean that *z*.

By using this structure, the author suggests that *x* and *y* are related phenomena. Specifically, *y* is an elaboration of *x*. To use the grammatical term, the noun phrase *y* is in **apposition** to the noun phrase *y*.

Comment: -1 for a poor answer containing several errors. For example, the _that_ clause is not a noun phrase but a declarative content clause. Note that the classification of finite subordinate clauses is based on their internal form rather than spurious analogies with the parts of speech.

Comment: (Note: the user above has a vendetta against me and has made several personal attacks in the past, which led me to report him for harrassment. He has consistently refused to engage with these reports.)

Comment: @BillJ, to engage with your content, aside from your behaviour, your use of 'spurious analogy' ignores an entire linguistic tradition which classifies nominalized clauses along with noun phrases. If, as you suggest, *that I like apples* is a finite subordinate clause, then what is the relativized element? An invisible "the fact"?

Comment: I don't follow you. Content clauses are not relative clauses, so where where does 'relativised element' come into it?